# (MyPy) Missing type parameters for generic type "ModelAdmin"

Tags: python, django, mypy

When I run mypy, I get this error:

```
emails/admin.py:43: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "ModelAdmin"
```

And this is the corresponding code snippet:

```
@admin.register(Message)
class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('subject', 'thread', 'user', 'email_account', 'from_name', 'from_email', 'local_timestamp')
    search_fields = ('subject','thread__synced_with_email', 'user__username', 'email_account__synced_email_current', 'from_name', 'from_email')
    ordering = ('subject', 'thread')
```

This class is not exactly a function so I do not understand why the type-hint is checked by mypy. There is nothing that gets returned and no parameters are passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because run-time dependency which mypy is unable to figure out.
To get rid of the error, you need to install `django_stubs_ext` like `pip install django-stubs-ext`.

Then in your settings file add these two lines.

```py
import django_stubs_ext
django_stubs_ext.monkeypatch()
```

Bind `admin.ModelAdmin` to specific model like `admin.ModelAdmin[Message]`.

Modify `admin.py` file like

```py
@admin.register(Message)
class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin[Message]):
    list_display = ('subject', 'thread', 'user', 'email_account', 'from_name', 'from_email', 'local_timestamp')
    search_fields = ('subject','thread__synced_with_email', 'user__username', 'email_account__synced_email_current', 'from_name', 'from_email')
    ordering = ('subject', 'thread')
```

The relevant [PR](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/pull/526/files) introduced the change.